# Sql-server: trigger and last inserted ID

Tags: php, sql-server, triggers, propel

I have a PHP application using a sql-server database and trigger. The workflow is the following:
- I create an object in the DB,
- a trigger logs the creation into a dedicated table, by inserting a row within,
- then from PHP I get the last inserted ID.

The problem is that the last inserted ID is related to the log row and not to my object.

From the PHP code, I cannot do in another way as this is done by my ORM (Propel). So I must make it work on the DB side. Is there any way to achieve it, eg by telling the trigger not to be considered as a "last inserted id' ?

Comment: Hey did you solve thi sproblem? I'm with the same issue. I'm using laravel 5 and I don't wanna change the framework code to solve it.

Comment: Not yet, I tried to create my own PDO class to implement the lastInsertId() method to return SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() but this always returns '0'. The strangest is that not all my trigger do not work, for few I can yet have the expected ID

Answer (score 1):

You have several options: `@@IDENTITY` vs `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` vs `IDENT_CURRENT`

1. `SELECT @@IDENTITY`

   It returns the last `IDENTITY` value produced on a connection, regardless of the table that produced the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.
2. `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

   It returns the last `IDENTITY` value produced on a connection and by a statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the value.
3. `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)`

   It returns the last `IDENTITY` value produced in a table, regardless of the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.

   `IDENT_CURRENT` is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. `IDENT_CURRENT` returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: The problem is that getting the last inserted ID is done from PHP code, by the Propel ORM, which runs a PDO::lastInsertId . I cannot change it. The better would be to do a kind of requests at the end of the trigger to restore the identity value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ***SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()*** in your stored procedure to get the last ID created in the current session, scope.

if you use *another option*, it will return the ID of  the Log table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Scope_Identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). This gets the last ID generated in the current session *and* scope (triggers run in their own scope).